# Running aspnet_regiis for encryption in loop exists after first failure/success operation

Tags: powershell, aspnet-regiis.exe

I am writing a powershell script which reads a CSV which includes path where Web.config/App.config resides applications. The script simple tries to encrypt the configuration files. A snippet of the code is as:

```
foreach ($config in $configs) {
  $rootPath = Get-Location
  $directory = Join-Path -Path $rootPath -ChildPath $config.GetPath()  

  if (Test-Path -Path $directory) {
     $configPath = Join-Path $directory -ChildPath $config.GetOriginalConfig()
     if (![System.IO.File]::Exists($configPath)) {
      Write-Host "$configPath was not found."
      return
    }
    # A set of helper codes

    Try {
      cd $directory
      # Invoke-Command $moveToDirectory
      aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings . -prov CustomProvider
    }
    Catch {
      Write-Host $$_.Exception.Message
    }
  }
}
```

The problem here is that I have 5 configuration path but only the first one runs and the application exists. It seems that `aspnet_regiis` exists the program in both success or failure case. What can I do to make it run in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well through some hit and trials, I was able to breakdown the problem. The loop was stopped to run because of: `cd $directory` command. My guess is that as the problem is commanded to change the directory, the script is not in its current scope. I am a newbie so this is just my guess.
So I changed a line of code to:

`aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings "$directory" -prov CustomProvider`